# How to track a mail in Gmail?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, gmail

I am making a chrome extension to track sent emails. I want to know when the email was opened.

But I have no idea how to do it as I am new to coding. Help is appreciated.

For your information, I am using Javascirpt. Thanks.

Comment: Please go thru this article . Here the  author has explained how it's done
https://www.codeproject.com/articles/15109/tracking-emails-for-open-read

Answer (score 0):

You can look at the page source code and go through the divs, I imagine opened emails have different class names than not read emails, because they have different colors.